# getting the following error while mapping from kafka to a csv file using spark as staging location in oracle data integrator 12C

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, oracle-data-integrator

```
ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed. 
ODIKM-SPARK-SYNC-10000: EKM Command Failed with Exception: java.lang.Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
10   File "/tmp/kafka_file_Physical.py", line 77, in <module>
11     ,"group.id" : "kafka_file_Physical"}, fromOffsets='earliest')
12   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 138, in createDirectStream
13 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! From the looks of it you've got an error in your python script. But you need to provide more information, rather than just an error message.

Comment: Looks like you used `str` as `fromOffsets`.